# Имеется ли возможность передать в декоратор self параметр объекта?

Tags: python, ооп, декоратор

Имеется несколько классов, методы которых нужно декорировать. Декоратор принимает один параметр.

```
def handle_pop_up(driver):
    def decorator(func):
        @wraps(func)
        def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
            original_window_handle = driver.current_window_handle
            switch_to_pop_up(driver)
            result = func(*args, **kwargs)
            driver.switch_to.window(original_window_handle)
            return result
        return wrapper
    return decorator
```

Параметр, который нужно передать в декоратор, должен получаться через значение текущего объекта, то есть через **self.driver**. Я попытался сделать следующим образом

```
@handle_pop_up(self.driver)
def connect(self) -> None:
    driver = self.driver
    WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
        EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//div[@data-testid="OAuth_Consent_Button"]'))).click()
```

Но IDE выдаёт ошибку **Unresolved reference 'self'**, то есть на таком уровне передать параметр не получится.

Каким образом можно попробовать передать self-аттрибут, не прибегая к следующему решению?

```
def connect(self) -> None:
    driver = self.driver

    @handle_pop_up(driver)
    def decorated():
        WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
            EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//div[@data-testid="OAuth_Consent_Button"]'))).click()

    decorated()
```

Answer (score 1):

Можно передать параметр self внутрь декоратора и с помощью его получить значение self.driver.

```
def handle_pop_up(func):
    @wraps(func)
    def wrapper(self, *args, **kwargs):
        driver = self.driver
        original_window_handle = driver.current_window_handle
        switch_to_pop_up(driver)
        result = func(self, *args, **kwargs)
        driver.switch_to.window(original_window_handle)
        return result

    return wrapper
```